# SQL query, How to return all records of dates between 15 and 20 days from now

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datediff

As title says, I've got table data of contract end dates and I need to return a list of all rows where the end date is between 15 and 20 days away from now. I have the following code:

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF([day], Contract.EndDate, GETDATE()) < 20) 
AND (Contract.EndDate < DATEADD([day], 15, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF([day], Contract.EndDate, GETDATE())  between 15 and 20`

Answer (score 2):

Your query will return the rows whose `contract.endate` less than 20 days from now. Try this `where` clause

```
DATEDIFF([day], Contract.EndDate, GETDATE()) between 15 and 20
```

Answer (score 2):

This is much better written as:

```
WHERE   Contract.EndDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 15, GETDATE())
AND     Contract.EndDate < DATEADD(DAY, 21, GETDATE())
```

*N.B I have assumed that you want to include things from the 20th day, so have added 21 days to `GETDATE()`, if this is an incorrect assumption then just change it to 20*

Doing it this way means the two constants (15 and 21 days ahead) are calculated once at run time, then no other functions are used, whereas if you use something like:

```
DATEDIFF([day], Contract.EndDate, GETDATE()) < 20
```

You have to perform the `DATEDIFF` function on every row, this means that any index that exists on `Contract.EndDate` cannot be used (the predicate is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)). Even if no index exists, despite being very little overhead, the `DATEDIFF` function still has a tiny bit, so why perform a function hundreds, thousands, maybe millions of times when once will suffice.

It is also mostly personal preference, because as long as you understand what `BETWEEN` is doing queries can be written correctly, but I **always** use an open ended range when working with dates (i.e `DATE >= X AND DATE < Y`). It is much clearer (IMO) and much less likely to cause unexpected results. Aaron Bertrand has written a very good article on the subject - [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

For what it is worth, the problem with your query is your two clauses are both specifying the date is less than a certain date:

```
WHERE   (DATEDIFF([day], Contract.EndDate, GETDATE()) < 20)
```

This will limit to rows where "EndDate" is less than 20 days in the future, which is desired behaviour, and the next clause

```
AND     (Contract.EndDate < DATEADD([day], 15, GETDATE()))
```

Will limit the rows to where the "EndDate" is less than 15 days in the future, which is not desired behaviour, the `<` in this second predicate should be `>`.

Using today as an example you essentially have a where clause that states

```
WHERE   Contract.EndDate < '2015-08-18'
AND     Contract.EndDate < '2015-08-13'
```

So you have the right upper limit, but this will also return all rows in the past.

Comment: What exactly is suppose to work here? Because non of it does.

Comment: The very first where clause is what is supposed to work: `WHERE Contract.EndDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 15, GETDATE()) AND Contract.EndDate < DATEADD(DAY, 21, GETDATE())` - If it does not work could you please elaborate as to why?

Comment: I do apologise, it works a treat. Must have been something wrong else where. Thank you very much for your help!